# How do I re-order data in the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

**AS-IS:**

```
ID       Version 
5587138  1
6460704  2
6537612  3
6264608  4
```

**TO-BE:**

```
ID       Version
5587138  1
6264608  2
6460704  3
6537612  4
```

I have to re-order the IDs to match the version order. The data is coming from the same table. I am currently trying to use PL/SQL. I really need help on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: But why?!? ID's are ID's, don't change them. Will mess up fk's etc.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying the VERSION order is trustworthy and the ID order is not. Is there any other column in play that you need to group by, or is VERSION unique in the table? If VERSION is reliable why not just use it for any sorting requirements. The main use of a technical key such ID is uniqueness, and it shouldn't carry any other meaning, not even order of creation.

Comment: @devloperMD . . . I don't think I recommend doing this.  But if you do, then `MERGE` is the best approach.

Comment: This works great. However, I forgot to mention that data (other columns) could have been modified per version. So...

ID             Version     Col
5587138       1          X
6460704       2          Y
6537612       3          Z
6264608       4          7

ID               Version   Col
5587138        1            X
6264608        2            7
6460704        3            Y
6537612        4            Z

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge` statement as follows:

```
merge into your_table trg
using (select id, row_number() over (order by id) as version from your_table) src
on (trg.id = src.id)
when matched then
update set trg.version = src.version;
```

Comment: I added more details.  

**AS-IS:**  
ID               Version     ColData
5587138       1                 A  
6460704       2                 B  
6537612       3                 C  
6264608       4                 2  

** TO-BE: **  
ID                Version    ColData
5587138       1                 A
6264608       2                 2
6460704       3                 B
6537612       4                 C

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be don't change the version numbers since if the same version is 
      there for more than one id but use the version no required 
      based on rownum

```
 SELECT ID,Coldata,rownum version
 FROM ( SELECT ID,Coldata, version FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID,Coldata);
```

Comment: This will not generate the required output as `rownum` is generated before the `ORDER BY` clause is executed which will not guarantee the correct ordering.