# How do I re-order rows that are out of sequence while maintaining data integrity?

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Example Data

```
**Current Data:**
ID               Version  Col1   Col2   Col3    Col4
5587138            1       C    Car     Gas     D
6460704            2       B    Bus     Diesel  A
6537612            3       B    Bus     Diesel  B
6264608            4       T    Truck   Gas     D

**2nd Result:**
ID                Version  Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
5587138            1        C     Car    Gas     D
*6264608*          2        B     Bus    Diesel  A
*6460704*          3        B     Bus    Diesel  B
*6537612*          4        T     Truck  Gas     D
```

I need to re-arrange (update) the above data such that I get the 2nd result. I have to keep the data for Col1, Col2, Col3, and Col4 with their respective versions. Your help is greatly needed and appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you've [asked this again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60993358/266304). Is your ID column a primary or unique key, and are they foreign key references to it? You also still haven't address why you want to change what look like synthetic key values.

Answer (score 0):

If your version starts from 1,2,3 ... then you can use the analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the row number based on the ID and update the ID for related version as follows:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE Y
SET ID = (SELECT ID FROM 
            (SELECT ID, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN 
               FROM YOUR_TABLE YIN)
          WHERE RN = Y.VERSION);
```